# ERROR The Compose file docker-compose is invalid because

Tags: docker

Estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa mensagem aparece ao executar o docker-compose.yml, dar uma olhada como ele se encontra!

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  kwan:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-kwan
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=POSTGRESQL
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata-teste:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 3s
    retries: 5
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network


networks: 
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Não sei como corrigir!**

Answer (score 0):

Arquivos YAML possuem notação baseada em indentação. Isso significa que deve-se dar o devido recuo quando definindo parâmetros de uma mesma configuração (por convenção, utiliza-se dois espaços em branco como recuo).

Seu erro foi na estrutura `services.kwan.healthcheck`. Ali você precisa corrigir a indentação conforme a [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck), dando o recuo para as chaves `test`, `interval`, `timeout` e `retries`, que fazem parte da configuração `healthcheck`.

Seu arquivo então deveria ser assim:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  kwan:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres-kwan
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=POSTGRESQL
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata-teste:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - postgres-compose-network


networks: 
  postgres-compose-network:
    driver: bridge
```